# Google Chrome Manual IPSec VPN

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, google-chrome-extensions, fritzbox

The Google Chrome browser features various VPN solutions in its [web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/vpn).
Those seem to be mostly for the "click here to hide your activity" type.

I'd like my Google Chrome installation to connect to my VPN at home, which uses an "IPSec Xauth PSK" connection from my FRITZ!Box 7590 router.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

IPSec tunnel works at a lower level of OSI than Chrome Browser. So it is not possible for the Browser to establish IPSec Tunnels. The applications you mentioned would usually Proxy Internet Traffic, or have a Client in local machine, which will be launched through the Chrome Browser.